# MySQL: Using alias in select arithmetic - Unknown field

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my select:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(t.amount + c.designFeeValue) as cashReceived, 
  ROUND(SUM(i.value) * (m.percentOurs / 100)) as adValue,
  m.managementFee as managementFee,
  m.productionCost as productionCost,
  5 as emailAddress,
  (
    (
      SELECT value
      FROM commission_transactions
      WHERE isDebit IS
      TRUE
    ) -
    (
      SELECT value
      FROM commission_transactions
      WHERE isDebit IS
      FALSE
    )
  ) as miscExpenses,
  (managementFee + productionCost + emailAddress + miscExpenses) as totalExpenses
```

This is bombing because of the following line, where I add up some aliases.

```
(managementFee + productionCost + emailAddress + miscExpenses) as totalExpenses
```

The aliases are unknown fields.

Is there a way I can keep the aliases for this arithmetic or do I need to re-do all the math that generates each alias for the calculation of totalExpenses?  That seems like a very ugly way to do it.

---

UPDATE:

Per your suggestions, I am now using a derived table.

```
SELECT 
  cashReceived,
  adValue,
  managementFee,
  productionCost,
  emailAddress,
  miscExpenses,
  adValue + managementFee + productionCost + emailAddress + miscExpenses as totalExpenses
FROM (
  SELECT
    SUM(t.amount + c.designFeeValue) as cashReceived,
    ROUND(SUM(i.value) * (m.percentOurs / 100)) as adValue,
    m.managementFee as managementFee,
    m.productionCost as productionCost,
    5 as emailAddress,
    (
      (
        SELECT value
        FROM commission_transactions
        WHERE isDebit IS TRUE
      ) -
      (
        SELECT value
        FROM commission_transactions
        WHERE isDebit IS FALSE
      )
    ) as miscExpenses  
  FROM magazines m
  JOIN insertions i ON i.magazineId = m.id
  JOIN transactions t ON t.insertionId = i.id
  JOIN contracts c ON i.contractId = c.id
  JOIN commission_transactions ct ON m.id = ct.magazineId
  WHERE m.id = 17
    AND t.isChargedBack IS FALSE
    AND t.`timestamp` >= '2013-08-01 00:00:00'
    AND t.`timestamp` < '2013-09-01 00:00:00'
    AND ct.createdDate >= '2013-08-01 00:00:00'
    AND ct.createdDate < '2013-09-01 00:00:00'
) sub;
```

Comment: Try either writing out yourTablesAlias.yourColumnAlias and if that doesn't work, redo the calculation. like `miscexpenses.managementFree + miscExpenses.productionCost`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aliases aren't available for re-use within the field list, e.g:

```
mysql> select 5 as five, five + 1 as six;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'five' in 'field list'
```

You'll have to wrap the select with another one, then do your alias math in that wrapper, e.g.

```
select *, managementFee + productionCost + emailAddress + miscExpenses) as totalExpenses
FROM (
   ... your above query here ...
)
```

Comment: This semicolon: `'2013-09-01 00:00:00';` at the end of your various dates should not be there. `;` is a statement terminator, but you haven't finished your query yet at that point which leaves at least one `(` open and dangling.

Comment: One more question, ... Strangely, cashReceived, adValue, and totalExpenses are NULL. These are fields that in the sub are generated by arithmetic.  How can I access these fields in the outer SELECT?

Comment: basically the outer/wrapper query sees the inner query as a table. as long as the outer uses the aliases/field names exactly as the inner query uses them, you should be getting data back.

Comment: Samething happens when I use * or sub.cashReceived.

Comment: if they're null in the outer query, they'd be coming back as null from the inner query as well.

Comment: You're right, the inner query returns null too.  Wonder how that happened.  I'll investigate.  Thanks.